# Flutter app launch janky and need optimisations

Tags: flutter

The app I have created seems to open quite slow (and janky) compared to other apps on my phone. It only seems to happen on android

I have tried copying the dependencies to a new project and running it and it doesn't replicate the same behaviour.

I have also changed the original app to only load a red container in the matierial app but its still really choppy on app launch before it loads.

I would post some code but I am not entirely sure whats wrong.

Sorry this is quite vague but I am running out of ideas. I dont really want to have to recreate everything in a new project.

Please note I have done the android v2 migration so it could potentially be linked to this?

Does anyone have any ideas to what could be causing it?

Update:

Forgot to mention this is on profile/release mode.. its not debug mode causing it

Comment: It will nearly always be janky in debug mode.  Do you still have the little "debug" sash across the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's hard to know why your app is being so "janky" but i'm going to make a few shots in the dark:

Are you running this on an emulator or on a real phone? Emulators will sometimes act weird, and will deliver results that you might not see on an actual android device. If you are running this on an emulator, try launching it on a physical phone. I have had experience with using Android emulators and sometimes trying to open the app at all becomes weird. How old your phone is might also be the cause of this, if it is old.

Do you have too many tabs open? Try exiting out of all of your applications and then open up your flutter app. See if that does anything.

That is all that I have concerning the environment that you are working in. You haven't posted any code, so i'm going to have to ask you about what your app is doing on startup. It would be good if you posted some code or a link to a git repository so that I can see that and be of better help.

Comment: Fixed it by changing the startup theme to parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" ..... After copying code into a new project this was one of the only differences. I appreciate you trying to help me :)